# Stuck at Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-client

I want to call a method of solana smartcontract. I have an IDL. While I'm calling it I'm getting the following error (when I'm calling await this.program.methods.initialize() method):

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0

```
this.anchorProvider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(this.anchorProvider);

const mintAccount = await createMint(
  this.anchorProvider.connection,
  this.payerKey,
  this.mintAuthorityKey.publicKey,
  null,
  DECIMALS
);

const [pdaGlobalAccount] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("global")],
  this.program.programId
);
const [pdaEscrow] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("escrow")],
  this.program.programId
);
// console.log('pdaGlobalAccount', pdaGlobalAccount.toBase58())

// Test initialize instruction
let init = await this.program.methods
  .initialize()
  .accounts({
    globalState: pdaGlobalAccount,
    escrowAccount: pdaEscrow,
    mint: mintAccount,
    authority: this.adminKey.publicKey,
    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
  })
  .signers([this.adminKey])
  .rpc();

const result = await this.confirmTransaction(init);
```

here is confirmTransaction method:

```
async confirmTransaction(tx: string) {
  const latestBlockHash = await this.anchorProvider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  return await this.anchorProvider.connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: tx
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x0` means you're attempting to initialize an already initialized account. What's happening here is that because your PDAs have only constant seeds, the same address is generated for them on each run of the test.

Therefore, not only does running your test for the first time initialize `pdaGlobalAccount` and `pdaEscrow`, but subsequent tests also fail because they would attempt to initialize the same accounts as the first (because constant seeds give you the exact same address each time).

Comment: ah, that seems to be the case for me as well. Now the next question is, how to reset everything so that I can initialize again? I stopped `solana-test-validator` and restarted it.. and then ran the tests again `anchor test --skip-local-validator`. But I see the same error. That means the state is persistent. How do I clear/reset it?

Comment: Also, where can I get the list of these error codes (numbers) and their meaning/explanation? Where did you learn that _"`0x0` means you're attempting to initialize an already initialized account"_?

Comment: `solana-test-validator -r` resets the validator. You can also do this manually by deleting the test-ledger file. 

I wish I could give you a good answer to the second question. I'd recomment viewing the program logs though for more context on errors. An easy way to do this is `solana logs` or just try..catch in javascript

Comment: `solana-test-validator -r` is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. As for the second question, hope as the adoption increases, the docs also gets better.

Comment: Re: error codes and their meaning. You can find the codes for system errors [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a94920a4eadf1008fc292e47e041c1b3b0d949df/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L21-L22)